# IsolatedStorage in Window Phone 7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am working with IsolatedStorage in Windows Phone 7.5. I am trying to read some text from a file. But the debugger says the operation is not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream. Why?

```
//Read the file from the specified location.
fileReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("info.dat", FileMode.Open, fileStorage));
//Read the contents of the file (the only line we created).
string textFile = fileReader.ReadLine();

//Write the contents of the file to the MEssageBlock on the page.
MessageBox.Show(textFile);
fileReader.Close();
```

UPD my new code

object _syncObject = new object();

```
                        lock (_syncObject)
                        {
                            using (var fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                            {

                                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("/info.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                                {
                                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                                    {


                                        string textFile = reader.ReadLine();
                                        MessageBox.Show(textFile);

                                    }
                                }
                            }


                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace. Is it in the IsolatedStorageFileStream constructor, or when you try to read a line?

Comment: @jon-skeet When i initialize 'fileReader';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it works for me: Hope it works for you too

```
        String sb;

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, myIsolatedStorage));

                sb = reader.ReadToEnd();

                reader.Close();
            }

            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sb))
            {
                 MessageBox.Show(sb);
            }
        }
```

If this doesn't work, then maybe your file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when I've used isolated storage, I've done something like:

```
using (var stream = fileStorage.OpenFile("info.dat", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

... rather than calling the constructor directly on `IsolatedStorageFileStream`. I can't say for sure whether that'll sort it out, but it's worth a try...

Comment: I change my code? but on this line: using (var stream = fileStorage.OpenFile("info.dat", FileMode.Open)) debager say Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

Comment: Are you *sure* you've managed to store the file correctly? You're sure that doesn't refer to a directory, for example? How are you initializing `fileStorage`?

Comment: IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

Comment: @user1597524: Did you definitely close the other stream when you created the file? This is very strange...

Comment: Yes. Of cource.I use lock(_someobj)

Comment: @user1597524: That doesn't close the stream. Locking is about multi-threading, not closing resources. Did you use a `using` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:

- WP emulator will reset all Isolatd Storage contents when it's closed
- if you used *FileMode.Open* with a path to a non existing file you'll get *Operation not permited* exception.

You can use `fileStorage.FileExists()` to check if the file is there or use `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`.